# how to make a rollbutton work with a rollcounter in a yahtzee game c#

Tags: c#

so i have been working on this yahtzee game and i have gotten the dice numbers and roll button working, now i want to add a rollcount label which tells how many rolls a player has left and after the amount of rolls is none it disables the roll button, this is my code so far for the roll button

```
    private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] dice = new int[5];
        Globals.RollCounter += 1;

        if (chk1.Checked == false)
        {
            dice[0] = random.Next(1, 7);
            lblDie1.Text = Convert.ToString(dice[0]);
        }
        if (chk2.Checked == false)
        {
            dice[1] = random.Next(1, 7);
            lblDie2.Text = Convert.ToString(dice[1]);
        }
        if (chk3.Checked == false)
        {
            dice[2] = random.Next(1, 7);
            lblDie3.Text = Convert.ToString(dice[2]);
        }
        if (chk4.Checked == false)
        {
            dice[3] = random.Next(1, 7);
            lblDie4.Text = Convert.ToString(dice[3]);
        }
        if (chk5.Checked == false)
        {
            dice[4] = random.Next(1, 7);
            lblDie5.Text = Convert.ToString(dice[4]);
        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void lblRollCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}
 the lblrollcount label is where i am supposed to put the code but none of my codes work[image]

this picture is how it's supposed to look after one click on the roll button, it goes in order and when no rolls are left the roll button should disable
and also can someone tell me how to arrange the numbers in numerical order